# com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status .getStatus() Cannot Resolve

Tags: location, status

I'm trying to use FusedLocationApi in my Android app to retrieve Last Known Location following this guideline : https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html

I have some problem with *result* class. On my code:

```
final PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

...
final Status status = result.getStatus();
```

On *result.getStatus();* my IDE notify me *Cannot resolve method 'GetStatus()'* .
I import *library com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status* .

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you already solved the problem, but this is just for someone who might be facing the same problem.....

*PendingResult*'s object is not the one you should use to call *getStatus*.
Instead, you call the method using *LocationSettingsResult*'s object (This is the class that conatains the getStatus() method) which is an argument to the *onResult* method.

This is what it looks like->

```
    private void getLocationSettings() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    final PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
            final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        }
    });
}
```